# Returning the First Number of a List

Tags: python, list, generator

So, I'm trying to create a script where the first even number of a determined list is returned. If the list contains no even numbers it returns -1.

At first I was trying to use `str.find()`, but I just don't know how to make it work.
Any help?

```
from typing import List

def f_even(items: List[int]) -> int:
"""
>>>f_even([1, 3, 4, 6])
4
>>>f_even([1, 3])
-1
"""
even_numbers = []
even = even_numbers[0]

for number in items:   
    if number % 2 == 0:
        even_numbers.append(number)                
return even
```

Right now I get an error where even = even_numbers[0]; the index is out of range. I feel like I'm complicating this code a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `if/else` block before you attempt to call `even[0]`, if your `even` has values then you can call `even[0]` else return/print `-1`

```
even = []
for number in items:
    if not number % 2:
        even.append(number)
if even:
    print(even[0])
else:
    print(-1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `next()` on a generator and return `-1` for no-even case.

```
lst = [1, 3, 4, 6]
print(next((x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0), -1))
# 4
```

On special case (*no evens*):

```
lst = [1, 3, 3, 9]
print(next((x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0), -1))
# -1
```

Comment: Technically, it's not correct to imply that providing the second argument is handling the exception.  Rather, the exception isn't being raised when the iterable is empty.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh, I worded it wrong. Thank you for your good eye.

Comment: Thank you for helping :); although, can' t use next() in my function

Comment: @JuanSBernal, if you are allowed to use it, you can definitely use it in your function.

Answer (score 0):

That's because right after you create `even_numbers`, the list is empty, and `even = even_numbers[0]` tries to get the first element of it, which is not there.

You can assign `-1` to `even`, and then update it in the loop. If there's no even number in the loop, it will still be -1, so the method would return -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [1,3,5,7]

def even(x):
  for a in x:
    if a%2==0:
      f = 0
      break
  else:
    f = -1

  return f

print(a,even(a))
print(b,even(b))
```

OP:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4], 0)
([1, 3, 5, 7], -1)
```